# Can I limit Windows 7 or 10 VPN users access

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, remote-access, restrictions

I'm about to set up a simple network and i need to give some ppl remote access and am thinking about setting up windows VPN for that.
Imagine I have 10 routers on this network and I need to give some users access to these 10 routers setup pages and only that !
is it possible to put some restriction on vpn users so they can only access a range of ip in a network and nothing more?(eg no file sharing , no RDP and no nothing)
really appreciate it if u guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. From Windows Server 2008 on NPS is included when installing RRAS. You can set "IP Filter" rules per user/group for authenticated users.